# Distinct - which items are taken? The first or the last occurance?

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

If I use following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT comment FROM table;
```

And I have for example following data: (IDs are just there to SHOW the order...)

```
ID | comment
-------------
1  | comment1
2  | comment1
3  | comment2
4  | comment1
```

What I could get back are following three results:

*Result 1:*

```
1  | comment1
3  | comment2
```

*Result 2:*

```
3  | comment2
4  | comment1
```

*Result 3:*

```
order is unpredicatable
```

**Question 1:**

Is the result independant from the platform? Can I make sure, that I always get a predictable result?

**Question 2:**

I want to distinct select all comments and get the NEWEST only, meaning I want to always get result 2. Is it possible to achive that? Maybe ordering by the key would affect the result?

Comment: That query will not return either set of results because you are are not listing ID in the SELECT clause. Please rewrite the query or the results

Comment: Where did the space come from in result 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query doesn't request the ID column, only the comment column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT comment FROM table;
```

In the result, the ID is not included, so the row each value comes from is irrelevant.

```
comment1
comment2
```

As for how it will sort them, I think it depends on index order. I'll do a test to confirm:

```
mysql> create table t (id int primary key, comment varchar(100));

mysql> insert into t values
    -> (1, 'comment2'),
    -> (2, 'comment1'),
    -> (3, 'comment2'),
    -> (4, 'comment1');
```

The default order is that of the primary key:

```
mysql> select distinct comment from t;
+----------+
| comment  |
+----------+
| comment2 |
| comment1 |
+----------+
```

Whereas if we have an index on the requested column, it returns the values in index order:

```
mysql> create index i on t(comment);

mysql> select distinct comment from t;
+----------+
| comment  |
+----------+
| comment1 |
| comment2 |
+----------+
```

I'm assuming the InnoDB storage engine, because everyone should be using InnoDB. ;-)

---

Your last question indicates that you really want a query that doesn't involve DISTINCT at all, but it's a [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) question. This type of question is very common, and it has been asked and answered hundreds of times on StackOverflow. Follow the link and read the many solutions.

Comment: Yes, it depends on the index used. So, it can be different per execution. For one column like the example, I guess that whether it uses a index or not (and do a filesort), the order will be ascending. But I'm not sure.

Comment: actually, I added the id only for clarifying the order... And actually, I can test it myself... I can't find out, if I can be sure, that the order I get, if I test it, can be expected on every other machine/system as well...

Comment: @prom85  Why would you want to predict the order?  Isn't it better to establish it via ORDER BY?

Comment: So, if I have an index, I can be sure, that the order is always the same?

Comment: If you want order by the "latest ID", you can use `SELECT comment FROM table GROUP BY comment ORDER BY MAX(id);`

Comment: Yup; if you want to predict the order, you have to make it predictable by adding an ORDER BY clause.  In the absence of an ORDER BY clause, the result set sequence is not predictable — in general.  You may be able to get away without an ORDER BY for a long time, but some day, someone will change something and the order will change unless you have the ORDER BY clause there.

Comment: I would have to make a few joins (4 or 5 tables), to get a date on which I could sort... So I wanted to find out, if I could avoid this... What I need it for is a list for the user, with the last comments sorted by their insertion date, so to speak...

Comment: Without an ORDER BY, you're at the mercy of the implementation within MySQL, and this could change with the next version, it could be different in another storage engine, it could have unexpected changes if you fetch more than just the indexed column, etc.  **Just use ORDER BY.**

Comment: actually, I'm using it with a order by key... So this means, if I use it with the key, the result is predictable and will always be the same? I'm using `order by key desc`...

Comment: Yes, that's the meaning of ORDER BY, to make sure the result set has a specific order, by the values in the column you reference.

Comment: I know, what order by means, I just wasn't sure, what the database does, if it first orders and then distincts and takes the first occurance or the last occurance or an unpredictable... But now I know, how to make sure that the order of my result is predictable and the way I want it

Answer (score 1):

You can experiment and see which of the unique rows is returned, and you can experiment and see which order they're returned in, but that will only show you how things turn out with your experimental table, today, under the current database engine version. Bottom line:

- If you `SELECT DISTINCT comment` the `id` is immaterial because it's not in your `SELECT`
- If you don't `ORDER BY` the database will determine the order.

If you want the most recent distinct comment with its ID, this will work *every time* (*full disclosure: this replaces an earlier answer that works but was over-thinking the problem*):

```
SELECT comment, MAX(id)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY comment
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Note that the `ORDER BY 2 DESC` assumes that the higher the ID, the more recent the comment.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT comment FROM table ORDER BY id DESC` would not always work? But I see that your solution will give me what I want and is save

Comment: MySQL is the only database I know that will allow this query. Oracle and SQL Server, for example, won't let you `ORDER BY` a column that's not in the `SELECT` list if you use `SELECT DISTINCT`. That's because there's no concept of `ID` when you `SELECT DISTINCT comment`. The query could well work until the end of time, but it could just as easily break with the very next version - there's just no guarantee. That said, Bill knows his stuff and I tend to trust his answers.

Comment: @prom85 - please see my updated answer. I was completely overthinking the problem with my earlier queries; the new query will work well and should never break.

Comment: thanks, now I know how to make sure that the order is predictable

Answer (score 0):

If you select a single distinct column, the other will not be returned.

```
select distinct column from table
```

is the same result as

```
select column from table group by column
```

In both these cases, the sort order of column is unpredictable, depending on the execution plan which may vary with larger amounts of data, diferent table structures, diferent database versions

to mimic your result, one would have to do :

```
select id, column from table group by column
```

which is an illegal grouping. If your SQL mode permits it to run, ID will be random.

if you mean `select distinct * from table`, then all distinct rows will be returned, in your case all the table.